# Intensity values of Image frames change after conversion to video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I am using openCV to create videos of particular patterns. One of my patterns of size 35x35 looks like this

[image: pattern]

and the corresponding numerical entries in the underlying matrix look like this

[image]

My idea is to overlay the pattern onto a white background of size 260x346 and create a video where the pattern moves horizontally. The first frame would look something like this

[image]

I create the video using openCV with the following function

```
def move_square(pattern, background):
    '''
    The function creates a video of the pattern moving horizontally over a given background

    Parameters:
    -----------
    pattern: <np.array, 35x35>
        The pattern supposed to move over the background
    background: <np.array, 260x346>
        A white background of the given size 
    '''
    fourcc = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP42')
    video = VideoWriter('./videos/moving_pattern_for_sampling_exp.avi', fourcc, 30, (346, 260))
    background[112:147, 0:35] = pattern
    frame = background

    for _ in range(0, 346-30):
        video.write(cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB))
        shifted_frame =  np.roll(frame, 1, axis=1)
        frame = shifted_frame
        video.write(frame)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()
```

However if I read the frames of the above video using the following snippet

```
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/moving_pattern_for_sampling_exp.avi')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0

while success:
  cv2.imwrite("test/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file      
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1

im = cv2.imread('test/frame1.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
np.savetxt("image.csv", np.asarray(img),fmt='%i', delimiter=",")
```

and now view the frames, the values of the pattern in the frame are different from what they originally were.

[image]

Also the locations which were supposed to be white with a value of 255, have now been set to 252 throughout. What could be the reason for these discrepancies?

Comment: JPEG is lossy. It is allowed to change your data to make your file smaller. Use PNG if you want lossless compression.

Comment: Most video codecs will do you in, i.e. *"adjust"* your data, just the same as JPEG, by the way.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that the video codec was not right. I replaced my old codec with one of those lossless codecs and my problem was solved. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save an image with JPEG format, you lose quality, hence precision.
Here is an example of JPEG compression (you can find the full image [here](https://d2dybsqaihwlah.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/18071917/compression.jpg)):

[image: No compression]
[image: Compression]

You can observe the quality deterioration for the bird and the wood (in the full image).

As @Mark Setchell suggested, you can use PNG to avoid that, but beware that the more you have color variations in your image, the bigger will be your file.

If it an help, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats) briefly decribes the common file formats.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. While the png/jpeg issue might be true in general, it doesn't seem to be helping here. I modified the above functions to write and read everything in terms of png images instead of jpeg. However, I ended up getting the same discrepancy. Could some kind of loss be happening due to the video codecs?

Comment: I found that the problem also was in the video codec I'd used earlier. A lossless codec along with replacing .jpg with .png in the functions above solves the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it helps, the codec issue might be tough to find, well done.